# Inversion of an almost identity matrix

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Say we have a square matrix like so

```
1 c c c ... c
c 1 c c ... c
...
c c c c ... 1
```

What would be the inverse of this matrix? Calling an inv function is expensive, especially for a very large matrix. I am almost certain there's a simple formula to quickly find this inversion since the inversion also has a very similar form of

```
x y y y ... y
y x y y ... y
...
y y y y ... x
```

Though I am not sure what the exact formula is, I appreciate any help.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a pattern in the results, for a $2\times2$ matrix the inverse is $\frac1{(x+1)(1-x)}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -x \\ -x & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and then for a $3\times3$ the result is $\frac1{(2x+1)(x-1)}\begin{pmatrix}-x-1&x&x\\x&-x-1&x\\x&x&-x-1\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few examples with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%5B%5B1,c,c,c,c%5D,%5Bc,1,c,c,c%5D,%5Bc,c,1,c,c%5D,%5Bc,c,c,1,c%5D,%5Bc,c,c,c,1%5D%5D) seem to indicate that the inverse of that matrix has the same form, except that the diagonal element is $-((n-2)c+1)$ and we have to divide by the determinant, which seems to be $(n-1)c^2-(n-2)c-1=(c-1)((n-1)c+1)$.

Here is the inverse for $n=5$:

[image]

This is probably easy to prove directly or using that the original matrix is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the inverse matrix to
$$
M_{ij}=c+(1-c)\delta_{ij}\tag1
$$
has the form:
$$
M^{-1}_{ij}=y+(x-y)\delta_{ij}\tag2
$$
one easily obtains from
$$
M^{-1}M=I
$$
the equations:
$$\begin{align}
x+(n-1)y c&=1\\
x c+ y +(n-2)yc&=0
\end{align}.
$$
The equations can be easily solved giving the result:
$$
x=-\frac{(n-2)c+1}{(c-1)(1+(n-1)c)};\quad y=\frac{c}{(c-1)(1+(n-1)c)},
$$
which provided that $c\ne1$, $c\ne-\dfrac1{n-1} $ justifies the assumption $(2) $.